# Windows 10 default language input now switches @ and " due to a key I pressed and I can't get it back

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, input-languages, english

Like the title says: I already tried this solution and it did not work: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4496404/windows-10-manage-the-input-and-display-language#input_language

I was pressing Caps Lock multiple times when it happened. This is after the Windows 10 update which is 2020-06. Please help!

Comment: Try shift+ctrl.

Comment: Sounds like you are switching between US english and UK/Irish/other layout. Try holding the Windows key and pressing the space bar.

Comment: Compare [US english layout](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/globalization/keyboards/KBDUS.html) and [UK english layout](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/globalization/keyboards/KBDUK.html).